# how to use component-specific css style along with boostrap css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

For some reason I can only do either one based on my webpack config.

I would like my components to have specific .css files associated with them along with the bootstrap css styles.

I've added bootstrap as a module in my react app rather than a direct link to the CDN which I then import on my root app component. I am only using the css portion of boostrap, I am not including the jquery stuff.

If I use the following config, I can apply component-specific css styles no problem but my bootstrap style doesn't work properly. I lose my grid styles

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: combineLoaders([
    {
      loader: 'style-loader'
    }, {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    }
  ]),
  },
```

If I do the following config, my bootstrap works but then my component specific .css files no longer apply

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: combineLoaders([
    {
      loader: 'style-loader'
    }, {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      }
    }
  ]),
  },
```

the only difference is that I remove the query option for css-loader. Is there something I'm missing in my config? I've only started playing around with webpack so I'm quite new.